# Creating a mobile application for an pre-existing webapp using RubyMotion

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, mobile-application, rubymotion

I co-run an RoR webapp that essentially runs in the same way as FML, TFLN, and all those "submit your secrets" apps from around 2009 work. Users submit "secrets" with tags as to what kind of secrets they are, admins approve them, then users can view them by tag or all at once, and comment on the ones that get published. Simple enough.

I'm new to mobile development, I've done some work in AppCelerator and Cordova Phonegap but that's about the extent of it. Recently I've been looking into RubyMotion (for iOS) and Ruboto (the Android clone) for application development. The applications I've made in the past have been small standalone 'egg timer tutorial' kind of things and I'm not sure what goes into making an executable application that has the same functionality and the same database as the webapp.

I've read on here that when you make an iOS app using Xcode, your RoR needs to be able to compile into Objective C before you can begin. Is the same true when using RubyMotion?

Where should I begin?

Answer (score 0):

RubyMotion is quite enough different from Ruby on Rails. They have minimal resemblance in project structure, which will be a little familiar for RoR developer. Despite of injected TDD/BDD practices, RubyMotion has built-in weak test framework. Before you take full advantage of Ruby have to understand the principles of building applications for iOS/OS X platform, read a lot of Apple References (documentation), learn Objective-C as well. So easy start will not pass, as everyone expects from Rails. Most of time you will sort out Cocoa Touch/Cocoa API. And When you assume Cocoa philosophy, patterns, API you will be able to inject tasty Ruby features, like metaprogramming.

One more point is that in RubyMotion community dominates programmatical approach to build UI instead of XCode Interface Builder.
You can start with [RubyMotion developer center](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/). There you can find link to [RubyMotion samples repository](https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples). And tons of Apple References of course.